# Program won't display answer of program after running it and typing in the correct input

Tags: java, joptionpane

So I have my program, and it just won't run after the last question (which needs input).  My code is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HiConor
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String result; 
      int selection;
      int Entry;
      boolean isYes;
      System.out.print("Starting Program");
      System.out.print(".");
      System.out.print("");
      System.out.print(".");
      System.out.print("");
      System.out.print(".");
      System.out.print("");
      System.out.print(".");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello there!");
      selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you doing good?");
      boolean isNo;
      boolean isCancel;
      isNo = (selection == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
      isYes = (selection == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
      isCancel = (selection == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
      if(isYes){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yes?" + " That's nice to hear!");
         } 
      if(isNo){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No?" + " Well then, cheer up!");
         } 
      if(isCancel){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fine then, don't respond");
         }   
      Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?",
      "Mlg recess poofs",
      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      String userinput = input.next();
      if(userinput.equals("alex")){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "What a lovely name!");
         }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I have a feeling you're trolling me " + ". This is the end of the program. Goodbye.");
      }}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the user to enter their name in the input dialog or in standard input? You open an input dialog but do not read the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this

```
String userinput =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?",
      "Mlg recess poofs",
      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Remove:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String userinput = input.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your input methods. Do you want to get the user's response from a dialog box or from them typing in a console windows? You seem to be using `JOptionPane` so I'll assume you want the dialog. In that case you do not need to use a `Scanner` object at all.  The call to `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` is already returning whatever the user typed, but you're not saving it in any variable. Just do the following:

```
String userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?",
    "Mlg recess poofs",
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

and don't bother calling `input.next()`.